# How do I make this query use my model class which extends Magento's core model class?

Tags: magento-1.9, model, inheritance

```
class Ebuynow_Mdlogistics_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    public function getNewUnshippedOrders()
    {
        $orders = Mage::getModel('ebuynow_mdlogistics/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $order_ids)
            ->addFieldToFilter('ship_status', self::SHIP_STATUS_UNPROCESSED)
            ->load();

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    var_dump(get_class($order));
}
```

Output

```
string(22) "Mage_Sales_Model_Order"
```

Desired output

```
string(22) "Ebuynow_Mdlogistics_Model_Order"
```

How do I make sure the row objects returned by the query are cast to the child class and not the core class?

Comment: Can you share your config.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the constructor:

```
public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('ebuynow_mdlogistics/order');
    }
```

You should take a look at this post by inchoo http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/ on how to create a model.